# Sitecore Azure Rebuild index error : sending too many requests

Tags: azure-search

I am using Sitecore 8.2 update 3 with Azure search service(Basic) in our application. While rebuilding the index,we get below error.

> 7980 08:34:38 INFO Schema synchronization failed
>    Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.AzureSearchServiceRESTCallException
>    Message: Error while search service call, see details in message
>    Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(HttpResponseMessage response)
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient.GetIndex()
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.SearchServiceSchemaSynchronizer.RefreshLocalSchema()
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchService.SyncSchema(Object state)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.AzureSearchServiceRESTCallException
>    Message: {"error":{"code":"","message":"You are sending too many requests. Please try again later."}}

I went through the Azure documentation for search-limits-quota-capacity but i don't find maximum number of requests we can make to Azure.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity

Number of fields is less than 1000 and
Batch size is set to 100 in our application.

How can i check the number of service requests we have made ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often encounter this error when there are too many indexes in the Azure search service. I use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to 1) get a [list of the indexes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/list-indexes) and 2) to [delete indexes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/delete-index) which are not needed (our setup means each developer has their own indexes in Azure search and we often hit the limits!).

Comment: I am using Basic tier of Azure service which is having a limit of 15 indexes and i am having 15 indexes in the service. So i thought i was within the limit. I think i need to delete and see.

Comment: Ok, so maybe you have a different problem... Or maybe its the case that by the time I've finished messing about deleting indexes, that's enough time to satisfy "try again later" suggestion ;-)

Answer (score 1):

We changed the azure search version in the connection string.

Requests before:

> https://MY_SEARCH_SERVICE.search.windows.net/indexes/sitecore-web-index?api-version=2015-02-28-preview

Requests after:

> https://MY_SEARCH_SERVICE.search.windows.net/indexes/sitecore-web-index?api-version=2016-09-01

If you are using API version **2015-02-28-Preview**, see if you can change that to a higher version.

Compatibility Table: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/549969

Answer (score 1):

We recently encountered the same issue on sitecore 9.2 version. It seems that there is a sitecore bug when SwitchOnRebuild feature is used affecting sitecore versions 9.0.2 upwards and it was fixed on 9.3.

After applying the fix downloaded from https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0983274 we are no longer getting the error.